# Pirkei Avos on Shabbos Tisha B'Av

Tags: minhag, shabbat, torah-study, tisha-bav, pirke-avot-ethicsof

When Tisha B'Av comes out on a Shabbos, do we say Pirkei Avos in the cycle on that Shabbos?

Comment: This question needs some clarification as to its intent. Please see the comments on the answer.

Comment: For a straightforward question, this is very ambiguous.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29990.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do not say them that week. Rama [OC 553:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%92)

Comment: Note that _Aruch Hashulchan_  rules that one should learn no less Torah than usual, even if that means he will learn things the _Rama_ bans. Presumably, then, he'd allow _pirke Avos_ if one would otherwise not learn Torah.

Comment: @msh210 Absolutely. I thought the OP was asking about the minhag of communal recitation following a set cycle.

Comment: (Oh, and _MB_ thinks one can rely on the same source the _AHS_ rules according to (the _Taz_).) I don't understand "I thought the OP was asking about the minhag of communal recitation following a set cycle": the _halachos_ we've quoted only mention reciting it, but presumably refer to reciting the 'correct' chapter, i.e. following a set cycle. (And if a community says it communally, that'd be even more of a reason to allow it (not _b'tzin'a_).)

Comment: @msh210 Does the Aruch HaShulchan say this about tisha be'av or about the Shabbos before?

Comment: @ba, _Shabas_ the ninth of _Av_.

Comment: @msh210 Meaning, every shul has a calendar with the same schedule for Pirkei Avot. While some communities may choose to study it or not, I'm answering if the calendar skips a week or not. It would be like asking if Daf Yomi skips that day (I have no idea if they do or not).

Comment: @DoubleAA (Strangely, they don't; Yerushalmi daf yomi does, though.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't see that _Rama_ comments on whether the common calendar skips a week. (He doesn't say "don't say _Avos_ this week and pick up with this week's chapter next week", and _AHS_ and _MB_ don't say "if you're learning _Avos_ this week then redo this week's next week anyway" (or "if you're learning _Avos_ this week then don't redo this week's next week: continue from where you are"). If you think the question's asking about the schedule (which it may be, I don't know), then I don't see how citing the _Rama_ helps.

Comment: @msh210 I hear what you are saying (that the rama is unclear) and I bli shevua will look up the maharil and more stuff inside tonight, but I'm pretty sure my conclusion is correct based on what I've heard from my shul rav and some other vague memories.

Comment: @msh210 I think it is hard to say that the Rama is referring to just stam learning avot and not the set cycle. First off, why use Avot as your example? Second consider the Maharil וכן מנהג שלא ללמוד תורה בערב ט' באב, וכן שלא לומר פרקים אם חל ט' באב בשבת and another Maharil citing a custom over the whole three weeks ובריינוס פוסקין מלומר פרקים and the Levush ולפיכך אם חל ט' באב בשבת ונדחה עד אחד בשבת או שחל באחד בשבת אין אומרים פרקים באותה שבת שהם במקום לימוד תורה כמו שנתבאר לעיל [סי' תצג ס"ד], and the Levush that the Levush referenced ובמנחה מתחילין לומר פרקים ממסכת אבות. Seems like the cycle.

Comment: Yes, good (the "Second" argument; the "First off" one is weak IMO, as that's something people learn so he'd mention it, but in any event...), but then that makes it likely that the _AHS_ holds we do keep to the cycle and the _MB_ holds we can keep to it.

Comment: @msh210 Re your first comment about betzina, remember that in the Rama's days they wore bigdei chol on shabbat. I agree that the AHS and MB would allow us to continue, but that doesn't mean the minhag is still to not say them (no worse than the minhag to not say avot in the winter). Go learn some other Torah!