# Shabbat on Tisha B'Av: any liturgical changes?

Tags: shabbat, tisha-bav

When Tisha B'Av falls on a weekday there are liturgical changes, plus (I've been taught) we refrain from singing in favor of just reciting, and we sit on the floor (as in mourning).  When Tisha B'Av falls on Shabbat we defer the fast and reading Eicha.  Do we make any changes to content or execution of the services on Shabbat (kabbalat shabbat, shacharit, mincha)?  Or is it a regular Shabbat as far as services are concerned?

I'm aware of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17695/472) about Shabbat restrictions on Tisha B'Av, but I think that's asking for something different.

Answer (score 2):

There are no liturgical changes at all from what is done on a "regular" Shabbat. The only exception is that *Tzidkatcha* is not recited during Shabbat Mincha, since *Tachanun* is not recited on Tish'a B'Av itself, and, although the fast itself is postponed, the calendar date, actually is Tish'a B'Av.

See [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17967/pirkei-avos-on-shabbos-tisha-bav?lq=1)  regarding reciting Pirkei Avot on this Shabbat.

One is allowed to eat meat for the "final meal". See *Magen Avraham* 552:14 that states that one should not have this meal with friends. (That's not liturgical, but you mentioned this in your question.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17967/759

Comment: Discussion about the status of 9 Av on Shabbat as a no-tachanun day (whatever that means) has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26156/discussion-on-answer-by-danf-shabbat-on-tisha-bav-any-liturgical-changes).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the Ezras Luach 5775 (this year):

> (Some have the custom to sing לכה
>   דודי in the melody of " אלי ציון ".) The
>   Haftorah is read (to the special melody
>   of Eichah) from Isaiah 1:1-27. אב הרחמים;
>   usual Mussaf; After midday one should
>   learn only those topics that are permitted
>   on Tisha B'Av itself. (There are authorities
>   who permit all learning Erev Tisha B'Av.
>   Mishne Berurah 553:10)
>   At Mincha we do not say צדקתך צדק.
>   We do not study Pirkei Avos. One may
>   drink wine and eat meat even at Seudah
>   Shlishis. However, we must stop eating
>   before sunset. Although it is still Shabbos,
>   we may not eat after sunset.

Mincha would be said early enough to allow everyone to return home and finish eating by sunset.  I have seen some Acharonim (I think the Chazon Ish) who were opposed to cantillating the Haftorah to the melody of Eichah.

Comment: Those all apply to Shabbat Chazon anyway. Nothing to do with Tisha Bav. If your answer is "none" you should clarify that.

Comment: @DoubleAA, well, all the parts that answer the question (seeking changes in liturgy) apply to any _shabas Chazon_. Except the bit about "_Tzidkas'cha_" -- but that was already covred by the earlier answer.

Comment: @msh210 Yes. Which makes this a pretty unclear answer, as above.

Comment: If Tisha B'Av on Shabbat = Shabbat Chazon then that's fine, but I did not know that when asking the question.  This appears to answer what I asked, which is what's different versus other shabbatot, though it sounds like some further clarification might be called for?

Comment: @MonicaCellio "Shabbat Chazon" is the Shabbat on which the Haftara is Isaiah 1 which starts with the word "Chazon" and is always the last Shabbat before the fast called "Tisha b'Av". It only falls on 9 Av in a year such as this one. It can also be 4, 6, or 8 Av. Customs relating to it (such as the tune of its Haftara) don't seem to answer your question AFAICT.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks.  I knew it was tied to that haftarah (which in turn is tied to Tisha b'Av) but didn't know whether there was anything else special about it.  I've never hear that alternate melody for לכה דודי, for example.  user4751, is there any difference between Shabbat Chazon on Tisha b'Av and Shabbat Chazon on some other date?

Comment: @MonicaCellio This is the tune https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jb89N-uPqwI Again, something that those who practice it do every year on whatever Shabbat is the last before the fast.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's true afaik but, well, who knows? Maybe some only do it on 9 _Av_. But the answer would need to support such a claim. (Incidentally, I'm surprised the _Luach_ mentions it. I'd thought of it as a preference of some prayer leaders, not a community custom.)